# rviz segfault in ros-electric

Tags: rviz, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed ros-electric. However, when I tried "rosrun rviz rviz", the error occurred as:
[ INFO] [1317134200.383469425]: rviz revision number 1.6.4
[ INFO] [1317134200.383560843]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1317134200.383580665]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
Segmentation fault

My os's version is ubuntu11.04, and gpu is ATI HD6630. Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11329/rviz-segfault-in-ros-electric/) by [kexiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/283/kexiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-27**:
The developers will probably need a gdb stack backtrace to help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi kexiang,
I suppose you have the same problem discussed here http://answers.ros.org/question/2109/rviz-in-ros-electric#3609

I think you should look at hersh 2nd answer. If you have still problems post the same things I posted in my last answer.

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kexiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/283/kexiang/) on 2011-09-27**:
Thank you for answering. Before your answer,I tried uninstall the closed driver of ATI, then rviz worked normally. However, it still gives out information:
[ INFO] [1317209727.036570342]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7